# How to install drivers?

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I've recently installed Xubuntu on my old PC which previously had windows xp. Now, when I switched to Xubuntu I am facing a few problems. Firstly I noticed that Ubuntu and its variants come with preinstalled drivers which is great but not for my old PC because it has an ATI Radeon xpress series 200 graphics card(onboard graphics with nearly 256 mb of video memory) and a sound card which used to run on some 'Realtek' sound drivers. In windows xp I used a 3rd party app called 'Drivermax' to update my drivers but with ubuntu I am not able to find any drivers(I googled alot) due to which the display quality is not very good(though fine) but my computers sound is like almost gone.
Even after maximising the sound I hear very little output from the speakers that too of very low quality. If someone knows a solution, please help! I'll be really thankful.

Comment: I suggest using some of the command line tools to find out what hardware your Xubuntu system can see, and post the relevant bits in your question to help contributors. A useful list is posted [here](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/). You may find the info useful yourself when browsing the [Ubuntu hardware information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport).